# Remove unused char from URL by javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove custom parameter from URL but something wrong I did

there is my javascript

```
var removeFilterHelper = function(param) {
            var loc = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/Project/Search' + location.search;
            location.href = loc
                .replace(param, '');
}
```

For example If I have like this url :

http://localhost:5000/Project/Search/?categoryId=50,categoryId=20&subCategoryId=10

removeFilterHelper("categoryId=50");

Here is result :

http://localhost:5000/Project/Search/?,categoryId=20&subCategoryId=10

Comment: Why are you trying to replace `,,`? There is no `,,` in `http://localhost:5000/Project/Search/?categoryId=50,categoryId=20&subCategoryId=10` , not even after you remove `categoryId=50`, because would make it `http://localhost:5000/Project/Search/?,categoryId=20&subCategoryId=10`

Comment: Have you tried `removeFilterHelp('categoryId=50,')`? Your second replace `(',,', '')` is expecting two `,,` but there is only one.

Comment: I need to remove parameter correctly

Answer (score 0):

Just add a comma to your param.

```js
var loc = "http://localhost:5000/Project/Search/?categoryId=50,categoryId=20&subCategoryId=10";
var param ="categoryId=50" + ','; // Also remove the trailing comma
console.log(loc.replace(param, ''))
```